# How to map browser dialog using capybara/selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

What is the best way to handle browser dialogs (with ok/cancel buttons) using capybara/selenium?

The way I found easiest is by running the following:

```
dialog = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
dialog.accept
```

Any thoughts for a better approach?

Whoever downed this post please give a valid reason... it's not helpful to down vote with no reason why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where possible, you should try to avoid using the underlying driver directly. By using Capybara's API, you would be (in theory) in a better position if you want to change driver's and there are driver API differences.

From [Capyabara's project page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#modals), the way to handle modal dialogs is:

> In drivers which support it, you can accept, dismiss and respond to
>   alerts, confirms and prompts.
>
> You can accept or dismiss alert messages by wrapping the code that
>   produces an alert in a block:
>
> ```
> accept_alert do
>   click_link('Show Alert')
> end
> ```
>
> You can accept or dismiss a confirmation by wrapping it in a block, as
>   well:
>
> ```
> dismiss_confirm do
>   click_link('Show Confirm')
> end
> ```
>
> You can accept or dismiss prompts as well, and also provide text to
>   fill in for the response:
>
> ```
> accept_prompt(with: 'Linus Torvalds') do
>   click_link('Show Prompt About Linux')
> end
> ```
>
> All modal methods return the message that was presented. So, you can
>   access the prompt message by assigning the return to a variable:
>
> ```
> message = accept_prompt(with: 'Linus Torvalds') do
>   click_link('Show Prompt About Linux')
> end
> expect(message).to eq('Who is the chief architect of Linux?')
> ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this option! looks cleaner!!